# Is there any risk of running both the fan and furnace at the same time?

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I am attempting to build my own thermostat using an arduino and a few relays and have been trying to map the appropriate wires so I don't damage my furnace/AC unit.

This is a picture of my thermostat, a Honeywell Focuspro 6000.

[image: Honeywell Focuspro 6000 wiring]

When I select Fan to on Rh and G are closed.
When I select Cooling, Rh, Y, and G are closed.
When I select Heating, R and W are closed.

What I am finding strange is when the heating kicks on, it turns on separately of the fan. However I can still turn the Fan on while the furnace is running. Is the secondary fan the blower motor for the furnace and is there any risk of running both the Fan and Furnace at the same time.

The furnace is a [N9MSB (B Series)](http://icpindexing.toddsit.com/documents/086477/44004441200.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## FAN ON

When the FAN switch on the thermostat is switched to the `ON` position, the thermostat energizes the `G` terminal. This tells the furnace to turn the blower motor on. If the furnace is equipped with a multi-speed motor, the motor will typically be in `HIGH` speed when the `G` terminal is energized.

## FAN AUTO

When the FAN switch on the thermostat is set to `AUTO`, the blower motor will only be turned on as needed.

## Heating

When in heating mode, the furnace itself controls the blower. When the thermostat gets cold, it calls for heat by energizing the `W` terminal (If you're using a heat pump, the `O` and/or `B` terminals could be energized as well). When this happens, the furnace initiates the firing sequence. The furnace will try to fire up, and if successful, will turn the blower on after a timed delay (20-30 seconds typically). When in heating mode, the blower will typically run at a slower speed (`LOW`, `MED LO`).

## Cooling

When in cooling mode, the furnace doesn't typically do much at all. When the thermostat is too hot, it usually energizes both the `Y` and `G` terminals (If you're using a heat pump, the `O` and/or `B` terminals could also be energized). The `Y` terminal tells the condensing unit (or heat pump) to turn on, while the `G` terminal tells the furnace to turn on the blower (again, at `HIGH` speed).

---

## Risks of having FAN switch ON when in heating mode

There are two minor concerns with having the FAN switch ON when in heating mode, but both are more related to efficiency than anything else. First, remember that when in heating mode, the furnace has a delay before turning on the blower. This delay is important, as it allows the furnace to heat up before it starts blowing. If there's no delay, the furnace will start blowing cool air around, and could take longer to reach peak operating temperature.

The second concern is that when the FAN switch is ON, the blower is run at `HIGH` speed. Furnaces typically prefer a slower speed when in heating mode, to allow the air enough time to pick up heat. If the air moves through the furnace too quickly, it may not pick up enough heat. This could lead to cooler air temperature at the registers, and a potential overheating risk for the furnace.

Furnace heating elements; whether gas burners, electric elements, etc., typically don't vary their heat output. They're either on, or off. The furnace relies on the air moving through it to remove the heat it generates. If the heat is not removed, the furnace will overheat. There are safety devices built in to the furnace, that turn the heating element off if it overheats. However, these devices are there to handle exceptions, and are not to be used as temperature control devices.

## tl;dr

Blowing around cold air, and overheating the furnace are the two risks I can think of.

---

Here's a very simple schematic of a thermostat, that might be helpful.

[image: Thermostat Schematic]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have a gas furnace. If so the furnace will fire and preheat the chamber before the fan engages. This help dissipate any cold air in the ductwork before it blows into the conditioned space. 
On page 22, Note #12 of your schematics there is a 25 second delay for heating. For cooling there is only two seconds delay.
For heating, this would be CPU controlled once the proving switches are engaged. See drawings on page 22 look for LPS, LGPS and HPS. Sound like you are on the right track, just wait for the fan to cycle on.

Comment: I don't think running the fan on high will cause the furnace to overheat.  You are moving more air, but not warming it up as much.

Answer (score 0):

Originally started as a comment on Vern's answer.

I don't think running the fan on high will cause the furnace to overheat.  You are moving more air, but not warming it up as much.  There may be a risk running  a fan at too slow a speed, as the air will come out very hot.  This is the scenario that may cause the furnace heat exchanger to get too hot. Furnaces are optimized for this.

Most furnaces have various cutout switches.  I had one furnace that didn't cut in the fan until the exhaust temp was up to some minimal value. 10-20 seconds.  Most also have a cutout temp if the flue or heat exchanger gets too warm.

A house can be more comfortable if you can rig a way for the fan to run at one speed when heating at a slower speed when not heating.  The win here is that the air is kept moving so you don't get a puddle of cold air by a window.  This in turn can mean you can set the thermostat lower.  Depending on the layout you can do this with some strategically placed ceiling fans which are incredibly efficient.